# SUMIFs multiple criteria is not working in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sumifs

I need to sum the values from different sheets with two conditions.

The sample layout as following, I'd like to sum the values when Name=Andy,and Type=XXX & ZZZ ; add 35+43+23+35+18

Help me!!

```
Name      Type      Value
Andy       XXX       35
Bill       XXX       27
Gino       XXX       48
Bill       YYY       35
Andy       ZZZ       43
Bill       ZZZ       67
Gino       XXX       58
Bill       YYY       25
Andy       XXX       23
Andy       XXX       35
Bill       YYY       17
Gino       XXX       44
Bill       YYY       51
Andy       ZZZ       18
Bill       ZZZ       73
Andy       MMM       18
Andy       XYZ       20
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=SUM(FILTER(1*C:C; A:A="Andy"; REGEXMATCH(B:B; "XXX|YYY")))
```